# Is possible to customize analysis views in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I'm not sure how to depict my question else this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7aMVV5LsEU). I can manage info with Pentaho analysis views, but I'm not sure if I can modify analysis views, or maybe I have to find a third party BI plugin. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How you want to analysis your Report??

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do is create a Pivot Table/Chart in Pentaho.

You have three choices currently, two are FOSS, and the third is in the Enterprise Edition.

You can use the built in Mondrian OLAP database to build an (R)OLAP cube.  This cube will be the equivalent of the Pivot Table. You'll then be able to use either of the FOSS viewers available to the BI suite.  The one that is built in is called JPivot and can be a bit clunky.  (and is now no longer used)

The alternative is now Saiku Analytics (http://www.meteorite.bi/products/saiku).  It fully integrates into the BA server and provides the same capabilities.

The third option will cost the price of an Enterprise License.  It's pretty powerful from what I've seen (I use Community Edition, but from watching the tech demos, EE's Analysis Tool is pretty cool).

Comment: PAT has now been replaced by Saiku (about 6 months ago) and is a much more impressive beast - now comparable to Analyzer (EE tool).  http://analytical-labs.com/

Comment: [Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is new web user interface pivot table front end tool to connect to OLAP cubes.